# How to test from which environment the file path is in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am having QAS, DEV and Prod environments. I am writing a console application. There will be some text files in one folder in each of the servers. I want to grab those text files and and do some process in the console application and move it to archive folders after processing. In order to do that, I want to test from which path the file is :

I want some thing similar to this :

```
 If Environment.MachineName.ToLower.StartsWith(" ") Then
            env = "p"
        ElseIf Environment.MachineName.ToLower.StartsWith(" ") Then
            env = "q"
        Else
            env = "d"
        End If
```

But I dont have any pattern like it...How to get similar functionality ...any other ways to do it...like checking the paths for each...

Comment: _" I am writing a console application"_ and the  `asp.net` tag?

Comment: If you have any settings that change between each environment, then you should not be hard-coding the settings.  You should store the settings externally, such as in the app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steven suggested, add a setting to App.Config:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <My.MySettings>
        <setting name="Environment" serializeAs="String">
            <value>DEV</value>
        </setting>
    </My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then in your code:

```
    If (My.Settings.Environment = "DEV") Then

    End If
```

You just have to modify the App.Config file on each machine so that it corresponds to the correct environment.